# Am I missing something with row reduction to find the determinant of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

\begin{bmatrix}4&-4&2&1\\1&2&0&3\\2&0&3&4\\0&3&2&1\end{bmatrix}

So we were tasked to find the discriminant of this matrix using row reduction. Now the problem is I have to do the reduction in a specific order where I only subtract $r$<sub>2</sub> ,$r$<sub>3</sub>, and $r$<sub>4</sub> with $r$<sub>1</sub> only. But one I reduce it to this matrix

\begin{bmatrix}4&-4&2&1\\0&3&-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{11}{4}\\0&2&2&\frac{7}{2}\\0&0&\frac{5}{2}&-\frac{7}{4}\end{bmatrix}

I always get it wrong after that.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep going: subtract $2/3$ times row 2 from row 3 to get $$\begin{bmatrix}4&-4&2&1\\0&3&-\frac12&\frac{11}4\\0&0&\frac73&\frac53\\0&0&\frac52&-\frac74\end{bmatrix}$$ after which the last step is to subtract $\frac{5/2}{7/3} = \frac{15}{14}$ times row 3 from row 4 to end up with $$\begin{bmatrix}4&-4&2&1\\0&3&-\frac12&\frac{11}4\\0&0&\frac73&\frac53\\0&0&0&-\frac{99}{28}\end{bmatrix}.$$ Since you haven’t shown any further work in your question, it’s impossible to say why you “always get it wrong,” but my guess would be that you’re making some simple arithmetic error somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\begin{vmatrix}4&-4&2&1\\1&2&0&3\\2&0&3&4\\0&3&2&1\end{vmatrix} = \frac18\begin{vmatrix}4&-4&2&1\\0&12&-2&11\\0&4&4&7\\0&3&2&1\end{vmatrix} $$

and then we can use Laplace on the first row or proceed further to obtain

$$=\frac18\frac1{12}\begin{vmatrix}4&-4&2&1\\0&12&-2&11\\0&0&14&10\\0&0&10&-7\end{vmatrix}=\frac18\frac1{12}\frac1{14}\begin{bmatrix}4&-4&2&1\\0&12&-2&11\\0&0&14&10\\0&0&0&-198\end{bmatrix}=-99$$